# What Linux/Unix software to use to convert html or pdf to doc?

Tags: linux, doc

I need to convert css styled (x)html or pdf to doc as accurately as possible and do it on Linux (and if possible also on Mac) from cli. Unfortunately OpenOffice can't handle the layout. Is there any such software or library, commercial of free? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [media-convert.com](http://media-convert.com/)